# Participle modifying a noun other than a subject

Tags: participles

Example: 
"John jumped over the girl shouting angrily."

I assume the participle construction replaces a relative clause in this case.
("who shouted angrily").

My question: 
Can a participle modifying a noun other than a subject also replace an adverbial clause?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't understand what you're referring to as the adverbial clause.

Comment: That's when a participle construction is used in place of an adverbial clause.

Comment: _John jumped over the girl shouting angrily_ is ambiguous. It can mean either that the girl was shouting, or that John was shouting while he jumped. As you say, it needs a subject, but there are two possible subjects and they're both grammatical.

Comment: I don't think so. If John was shouting this would read: "John jumped over the girl, shouting angrily." The comma makes the difference here.

Comment: Generally, clauses like this modify the nearest noun, so it's natural to assume that "shouting angrily" modifies "girl". If the intention is to modify "John", then as you said, inserting a comma after "girl" might help disambiguate. Btw, I don't know why you said "adverbial clause" -- relative clauses are not adverbial, they modify nouns and are often said to be adjective clauses.

Comment: Maybe I did not make myself clear enough: I was wondering whether a participle construction modifying a noun other than the subject ("girl" in this case) can be used in place of an adverbial clause as well (and not only in place of an adjective clause/a relative clause).